# passing an array to an object in js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass an array to an object:

```
function process(pid, size, time, IOCArray, IOCtimeA, status) {
    this.pid = pid;
    this.size = size;
    this.time = time;
    this.IOCtimeA = IOCtimeA; // should i use this?
    for (var j = 0; j < IOCArray.length; j++) {
        this.IOCArray[j] = IOCArray[j];
    } // or something like this?
    this.status = status;
}

proarray[ID] = new process(ID, size, time, IOCArray, IOCtimeA, status);
```

Now how can I access for example `proarray[5].IOCArray[4]`?
Actually I'm not sure how to use "this" for arrays.

Comment: You could just do `this.IOCArray = IOCArray.slice(0);` ?

Comment: Have you tried using `proarray[5].IOCArray[4]` as you say? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `this.IOCtimeA=IOCtimeA;`you assign the reference to the array. If you change `IOCtimeA`, `proarray[ID].IOCtimeA` will also change.

With the `for` loop, or using a trick from @adaneo, you will copy the values and create an independent array in there.

Comment: As shown, the for loop lacks initialization of the array. It needs `this.IOCArray = []`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your provided code, both of your suggested solutions are not ideal because if you set an object's property to another array, you are just setting a reference to the original array. If you were to modify your object's array property, then you are also going to modify the original array.

Instead, what you are going to have to use is the `slice()` method. This will create a new, independent copy of the array for your object.

example:

`this.IOCArray = IOCArray.slice();`

It is also worth noting that `.slice()` will only make a shallow copy of an array. Nested arrays will be setting a reference to original nested array, so if you know you will have nested array's in any of your variables, you'll need to `slice()` those nested arrays as well.

[Array.prototype.slice() | MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)